# Wordpress dynamically add hook to theme template.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to dynamically add hooks to the themes template.php, like in top-a, or bottom-b?

Comment: Why not just edit the template?

Comment: Because I need to add content to it through a plugin's admin area.

Comment: Then why not just add the hooks in the template? (Or is that what you want? I am confused by the word "dynamically")

Comment: that's the problem.. I want it to be a general plugin, so I can use it in other wordpress projects without having to edit the template.php each time I install the plugin just to add the hooks.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think there are general hooks for the header area of the page, and the end of the `<body>`. Would those work? I don't think there is a way to add hooks *anywhere* in the template, at least not any sane way.

Comment: there is way to add hooks in nav bar by applying filter . you can use that.

Comment: What do you want those `dynamic hooks` to do? when will they be fired and by who?

Comment: I need more specific hooks. These hooks will be fired by the plugin itself.

Comment: ok, what's wrong with using the regular `add_action()` method? you can pass any string as the hook name, and you can manage the dynamicality of it (is dynamicality even a word?)

Comment: that was my first thought, but how can I pass the string to that speecific location?.. Another solution would be through javascript, but I don't think it's such a good idea.

Comment: there are no magic "specific locations". all the hooks that are called are being called in the template. they are just the "standard", so all the themes use them (like `wp_head()`). maybe you can use one of them for your needs, but there aren't hooks that fire in the `top` or `bottom` because those are theme-specific

Answer (score 0):

You can try to register in another hook. The hook *`setup_theme`*  is called before theme *functions.php* is included and *`after_setup_theme`* afterwards.

So you register one hook which then registers the other hooks.

See as well:

- [Wordpress 3.0 Program Flow File Inclusions](http://toolpress.de/tools/Toolpress_-_Wordpress-3.0-Program-Flow-0.2-2010-06-28.pdf)

Comment: I didn't quite understand how to do this with `setup_theme` hook. Could you be more specific?.. An example if I'm not asking too much?

Comment: Well how would you have registered your hooks inside *template.php*? Do the same just inside a callback in your plugin php script registered to be execute just *before* or *after* the *template.php*  is loaded. If that is unclear to you I suggest you give a better example in your question what you try to achieve (even if you don't know yet how).

Comment: I don't know how to get to that specific location in the template.php file, like top-b, bottom-a, etc. That's my main problem.

Comment: Show the code that shows that specific position. Just as it is right now. If you're concerned about sidebars in specific, they have their own hooks, too.

Comment: it's a custom theme, template.php is the equivalent to single.php (or something like that). I'm not interested in sidebar hooks.. or top-b and bottom-a are in sidebar? `<section id="bottom-a" class="grid-block"></section>`

Comment: oh you mean DOM manipulation of the output. That is possible with output buffering in PHP which is not specific to wordpress: http://php.net/book.outcontrol - DOM manipulation can be done with DOMDocument.